# MonoTouch native resource management

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios

Example:

```
var image = UIImage.FromFile("/path/to/image.png");
var imageView = new UIImageView();
imageView.Image = image;
image.Dispose();
```

Will the native reference from the UIImageView keep the underlying native image alive or will this crash sooner or later because the native image is actually dead?

**Update:**

```
void Foo()
{
  var image = UIImage.FromFile("/path/to/image.png");
  this.imageView = new UIImageView();
  this.imageView.Image = image;
}
```

Will this leak the underlying native image?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. The native UIImageView will keep a reference to the image, so it won't crash.
2. No, it will not leak the underlying native image. But it might end up freed *a lot* later than you'd expect. We recommend you call Dispose once you're done with images, since they tend to use a lot of memory which the garbage collector doesn't know about.

Comment: So they get freed by the finalizer.